# WebView and SSLSocket

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have custom `SSLSoсket` that works great with `HttpsUrlConnection` or `OkHttp` **library**. How do I make friends with my socket `WebView`?

```
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(new OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl());
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(isPostRequest(method));
        connection.setRequestMethod(method);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView does not use SSLSocket. It does, however, use the currently installed X509TrustManager (obtained via the highest-priority TrustManagerFactory). Thus, if your customizations to SSLSocket/SSLSocketFactory are solely about using a custom X509TrustManager, then you can make WebView use that custom X509TrustManager as well if you install your own TrustManagerFactory as the highest priority implementation. You're out of luck for any other customizations (e.g., different list of enabled cipher suites).

Comment: I want open my website with custom cipher suite throught webview. How I can do that? I find solution use HttpsUrlConnection in shouldInterceptRequest(WebViewClient) but I think this is bad decision.